# Ошибка при чтении файла java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

Tags: java

Почему выдаёт ошибку?

```
 String fileName = "settings.txt";

 String text = "AdresProgramm =";
 String delimiter = ";";

 Optional<String> result =
     Files
         .lines(Paths.get(fileName))
         .filter(e -> e.contains(text))
         .map(e -> {
             int start = e.indexOf(text);
             int end = e.indexOf(delimiter, start + text.length());

                 return e.substring(start, end);
         })
         .findFirst();

 result.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Содержимое файла: `AdresProgramm =D:\\ЭСЧФ\;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MalformedInputException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/MalformedInputException.html) возникает если содержимое файла не соответствует заданной кодировке.

> Checked exception thrown when an input byte sequence is not legal for given charset, or an input character sequence is not a legal sixteen-bit Unicode sequence.

Кодировкой по умолчанию является [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Либо сохраните файл в UTF-8, либо задайте нужную кодировку через [Files.lines(Path, Charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-)

```
Files.
    lines(Paths.get(fileName), Charset.forName("windows-1251"))
```