# Не читается файл, Java

Tags: java

Пишу текстовый редактор на java. Читает и выводит все без проблем, но только английскую кодировку.

```
public void loadText(File f) throws IOException {
    List<String> text = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(f.toString()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    for (String line : text) {
        area.append(line + "\n");
    }
}
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: ошибки какие?  кодировка файла?

Comment: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644584/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-java-nio-charset-malformedinputexception-input-length

Comment: огромное спасибо!